# How can I include React useState in a custom gutenberg block plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor, react

The block code is as such:

```
  wp.blocks.registerBlockType('myblocks/gallery', {
  title: 'Gallery',
  icon: 'my-gallery',
  category: 'common',
  attributes: {
  },

  edit: props => {
    const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const handleFiles = (files) => {
      
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        if (validateFile(files[i])) {

        } else {
      

      //the code goes on...
```

It of course produces `useState is not defined` error, but I've no idea how to import it. When I attempt `const {useState} = require( '@wordpress/element' );`, I get a `referenceError: require is not defined` ; and I don't know where to place `import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';`

I'm probably misunderstanding the fundamental structure, since I'm new to Wordpress development, but I've no idea where to go from .

Comment: it looks like you're doing this without any build tools for JSX, which means things like `return <p className={ classesVariable }>{ variable}</p>` or `import { useState } from `@wordpress/element';` won't work. This isn't necessarily a WordPress thing but a modern JS/React thing. Also if you want a custom gallery, it's much easier to reuse the existing gallery with a block variant than to rebuild the entire thing from scratch as a brand new block, likewise if your gallery just looks different a block style will do the job just as well if not better

Comment: Yeah I ended up adding JSX support. The gallery needs to automatically assign size to its elements based on their dimension so it seems to me writing one from scratch is easier than searching for a block that can do that.

Comment: You don't need to find a 3rd party block or create a new one. If the HTML is the same you can use a block style and then run JS or CSS on galleries with that class. Look at how Jetpack adds a tiled gallery option to the default core block without creating new gallery blocks.

Comment: Oh man that is totally what I should have done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just lucked upon an [answer](https://salferrarello.com/wordpress-gutenberg-functional-component-usestate/).
Added

```js
const {
    element: {
        useState,
    },
} = wp;
```

at the top of the file, it seemingly works, though I still have no idea what is going on.

Comment: this is the same as `const useState = window.wp.element.useState;` but does it using object destructuring instead which is a modern javascript syntax. I fixed the indentation in the code as the broken indents make it harder to understand and read